# Which salutation should I use in email, in which not the owner of the email replies?

Tags: email

I am sending my homework assignment via email to a person A, but the response email with a correction always comes from different person B and different email. So I am not sure which salutation should I use.

If I keep addressing email to person A, then, in a sense, I am ignoring person B.

And, otherwise, it does not feel right to salute person B in an email which has to be sent to the person A.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: [When should I use Mrs. or Ms. in emails?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/30/29)

Comment: Need more information. Salutations depend largely on your relationship with the person in question, in emails and in person. Are 'Person A' and 'Person B' tutors? Friends? How well do you know them? How would you greet them in real life?

Comment: In addition to what Astralbee said, is there a relation between person A and B, and what is it? Have you asked your classmates what they do?

Comment: @Astralbee,  Yes, person A is my tutor and I don't know B personally. Also I don't feel like casual salutation is  appropriate.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I have no idea, B might be a tutor for another group. They don't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Greet the person you're sending the email to

Yes you might have a different person respond but, unless you're copying person B into your emails too, you don't know what the situation is. Perhaps person A is struggling to keep up with their work load and B is just stepping in to help. In this case, addressing B is a rude reminder to A that not only did someone have to do their work but that its assumed that they can't.

If they forward it to B thats their prerogative but there is no need to greet person B yourself unless you're emailing them too. An example being:

> Dear (Title) A,

Or, if you are addressing both people:

> Dear (Title) A and (Title) B,

But only use this if the email is being sent to B as well.